How to troubleshoot a build failure for a react-native project in x-code?
My friend and I are mocking up an app with react native, so I cloned his repository, installed node.js and npm. I installed cocoapods and I installed pods in the ios directory. Everything that I installed seems to be up to date and we are running the same versions. However, when I load up the workspace in xcode, every time I build the project and load up the simulator, I am notified that the build failed and I get this error:
Showing Recent Messages
/Users/adocys/stampmind/ios/DerivedData/StampMind/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/hermes-engine.build/Script-46EB2E0001BE00.sh: line 9: /Users/jeonghwan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.4/bin/node: No such file or directory
my user is adocys and his is jeonghwan, so I guessed it has something to do with me downloading his repository but I have no idea what most of this stuff is doing so idk
I tried to build this react native project through an xcode workspace and it keeps erroring as indicated. reinstalling all the dependencies, the simulator, and the project files did not help. Since I don't know how this is being built I couldn't really troubleshoot without knowing what to look up online. Any and all input is greatly appreciated

I don't think this is a gitquestion.

Hey the error you're encountering might be related to a mismatch in Node.js environments between your setup and your friends setup The path listed (/Users/jeonghwan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.4/bin/node) suggests that the build is expecting to use your friend's Node.js version, which is being managed via NVM (Node Version Manager), but it's missing on your machine. Hope this helps!
